# How to extract results from a Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, var

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDatabaseEntities entities = new MyDatabaseEntities();

        var result = from c in entities.Categories
                        join p in entities.Products on c.ID equals p.IDCategory
                        group p by c.Name into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = g.Key,
                            Count = g.Count()
                        };

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

How can I extract the values from ths result set so I can work with them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    var name = item.Name;
    var count = item.Count;
    ...
}
```

This will only work inside the same method where the LINQ query is located, since the compiler will only then know which properties are available in the anonymous object type (`new { }`) used in your LINQ `select`.

If you return a LINQ query to a calling method, and you want to access it in the way shown above, you'd have to define an explicit type and use it in your LINQ query:

```
class NameCountType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

...

return from ... in ...
       ...
       select new NameCountType
              {
                  Name = ...,
                  Count = ...,
              };
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer when the timer ends. I'm a curious guy though; what data type is result exactly? I feel like I'm depending on magic a little too much.

Comment: _@Sergio:_ The compiler will generate an anonymous type for you with `Name` and `Count` defined. If you want to know exactly, you could use Reflection to inspect the details of the generated type.

Comment: @Sergio IQueryable<anonymous type> in your question.  IQueryable<NameCountType> in the last example of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
foreach (var x in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine(x.c.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var results = (from myRow in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                  where myRow.Field<String>("UserName") == "XXX"
                  select myRow).Distinct();
 foreach (DataRow dr in results)
    UserList += " , "+dr[0].ToString();
```