# Linq Join query 4 tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, xamarin, entity-framework-6

I am trying to join the four tables below, with the query below, but the i dont kown how to retrieve all the answers and questions associated with each Questionnaire, how can i do that?
With this query only retrieves one answer and question.

Thanks

```
var query = from x in db.Questionario
                        join y in db.Question on x.QuestionarioId equals y.QuestionarioId 
                        join j in db.Answer on y.QuestionId equals  j.QuestionId
                        join w in db.TypeAnswer on y.TypeAnswerId equals w.TypeAnswerId

                    select new QuestionarioAlldetails
            {

                TypesAnswer = w.TypesAnswer,
                Questiontext = y.Questiontext,
                Answerv=j.Answerv,
                Name=x.Name,

             };
```

Where I want to use the query output:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:InqueritogViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout>
    <Button Command="{Binding GetinqueritoCommand}" Text="Aceder a Questionarios"></Button>

    <ListView x:Name="InqueritoView" ItemsSource="{Binding Inqueritos}" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="ListView_OnItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout >
                            <Label x:Name="Label1" Text="{Binding Questiontext}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <controls:Checkbox></controls:Checkbox>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Answerv}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <controls:Checkbox></controls:Checkbox>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Answerv}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <controls:Checkbox></controls:Checkbox>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Answerv}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

[Tables data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Sg8.png)

[Output Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6xnt.png)

Comment: HINT: Use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: But how? for each question has to create a new variable, like question1, question2, etc.. , and answers the same.

Comment: It depends if your query is in the same scope as where you are calling it or not, regardless you should take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601301/how-to-extract-results-from-a-linq-query)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enumerate the results from your query like this

```
List<QuestionarioAlldetails> query = (from x in db.Questionario
                    join y in db.Question on x.QuestionarioId equals y.QuestionarioId 
                    join j in db.Answer on y.QuestionId equals  j.QuestionId
                    join w in db.TypeAnswer on y.TypeAnswerId equals w.TypeAnswerId

                select new QuestionarioAlldetails
        {

            TypesAnswer = w.TypesAnswer,
            Questiontext = y.Questiontext,
            Answerv=j.Answerv,
            Name=x.Name,

         }).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

To create a single row per questionnaire with multiple answer options, nest the results something like this;

```
List<Questionarios> query = (from x in db.Questionario
                select new Questionarios
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            Answers = (from y in db.Question  
                    join j in db.Answer on y.QuestionId equals  j.QuestionId
                    join w in db.TypeAnswer on y.TypeAnswerId equals w.TypeAnswerId
                    where y.QuestionarioId == x.QuestionarioId
                    select new Answer { 

                    TypesAnswer = w.TypesAnswer,
                   Questiontext = y.Questiontext,
                   Answerv=j.Answerv}).ToList()

                }).ToList();
```

(You need your Questionarios class to have a List property to hold the answer details)

You can then nest a list or stacklayout in your main stacklayout and set the datasource to the Answers property.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but is giving me the same output.

Comment: Phill, how is db defined - is it Entity Framework or a custom class?

Comment: If I mock up this exact query in LinqPad it works as expected so maybe there is an issue within the scoping of the db context?  You could try wrapping this query in a using(connectionname context = new connectionname) {...} or use something like LinqPad to isolate your query from the rest of your code.

Comment: I have the LinqPad5 installed, how can i test this?

Comment: I added a connection, then i selected Default(LINQ to SQL), then next, and finally ok. Now I can see my database, i have to right click in the database and then new query?

Comment: Do new query, change the type to C# Program and inside the Main() block put your query direct   var query = ...   etc.   Then you can click the run icon.  The trick to see the output is just after your query put  query.Dump();  and you will see the results displayed below the query.

Comment: Says db does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Just remove the db. from all tables as the connection is already made by LinqPad like - var query = from x in Questionario ...

Comment: Doesnt work, says " 'question' is a type, which is not valid for the given context "

Comment: Do you have the connection selected in the connection dropdown and are the table names correct?  They are case sensitive.  Is your query inside the main block?

Comment: The names where in plural in the database, now i can run, but isnt like i wanted, is creating 3 rows for the same Questionnaire, I want everything in a row, associated to that Questionnaire.
Output:
http://prntscr.com/fx8vbg

Comment: I don't think that will be possible because you could have a variable number of questions and this means you would need a variable number of columns in your QuestionarioAllDetails class which isn't possible.  Your original query is always going to create the same number of rows as there are question/answer combinations for each questionnaire.

Comment: I added to the Question where i want to use the query output.

Comment: Ah ok.  You need to return nested results from your Linq query and then use a nested stacklayout in the xaml form.  I'll update the answer with a small example.

Comment: Now the query is working, for your query to work, I had to create a AnswerDTO to replace the Answer that you had in the query.
But i want to get a list of questions too and the typeanswer of every question.
thanks.